# Pass null datetime using EF model-first

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-model-first

I use EF model-first in my application and use stored procedures too.

My table has a `LastStatus` column name of `datetime` datatype and it's nullable.

When the user fills in a `datetime` value, it works correctly.

Here is my code :

```
  (@StartAcceptDate IS NULL OR LastStatusDate >= @StartAcceptDate)
  AND  (@EndAcceptDate IS NULL OR LastStatusDate >= @EndAcceptDate)
```

But when user want to select all record release the date.

Many records have `null` value.

My question is here: how to pass `null` as a `datetime` from C# to SQL Server?

Comment: Datetime in C# is a type which is not null. If you don't provide its value it will get a default value.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to set the defaults parameters value to NULL in your stored procedure and you don't have to explicitly pass NULL to your stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc 
    (@param1 INT = NULL, 
     @param2 INT = NULL ....)
```

If you still want to send `NULL` from your C# code to your stored procedure, you can use `DBNull.Value`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your `DateTime` as nullable like this:

```
DateTime? StartAcceptDate;
DateTime? EndAcceptDate;
```

That way you can asign the value of `null` to the variables and send them that way to the database.